# simple jquery (DOM).click() function not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

The following simple html page is not responding to as it should when click on either "click" or "hide all paragraphs" button.I have included jquery lib "jquery-1.9.1.min.js" and I can see its all content in Firefox's 'view source page' by click it.This file's url in my browser is:**mylocalhost:8080/ajaxAppJquery/tryAjax.jsp**.Using Netbeans IDE.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Ajax Example</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#button").click(function(){
                alert("working");
                var url="http://localhost:8080/ajaxAppJquery/sayHello.jsp";

                $("#result").load(url);
            });

            $("#hide").click(function(){
                $("p").hide();
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="button" value="click" type="button"/>

        <input id="hide" value="hide all paragraphs" type="button"/>
        <p>paragraph 1</p>
        <p>paragraph 2</p>
        <p>paragraph 3</p>
        <p>paragraph 4</p>
        <p>paragraph 5</p>
        <p>paragraph 6</p>

        <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i click on #button it does not alert the message.Actually I am experimenting with jquery-ajax but it is not working with #hide button also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the html elements in script before they are available, You should put the script in `document.ready` or put the script just before the closing `body` tag

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
         alert("working");
         var url="http://localhost:8080/ajaxAppJquery/sayHello.jsp";
         $("#result").load(url);
     });

     $("#hide").click(function(){
         $("p").hide();
     })    
});
```

Comment: No worries, Some time we miss simple things.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your jquery code inside `$(document.ready(function() {})` or `$(function() {});` to let it see the whole DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        alert("working");
        var url="http://localhost:8080/ajaxAppJquery/sayHello.jsp";

        $("#result").load(url);
     });

     $("#hide").click(function(){
         $("p").hide();
     })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try to bind event after DOM ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function(){
    alert("working");
    var url="http://localhost:8080/ajaxAppJquery/sayHello.jsp";
    $("#result").load(url);
  });

  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  })
});
```